# Collectd Network plugins didn't open listening port

Tags: network-monitoring, collectd

I tried to send the monitoring data to my centralized collectd and found this error in the log

```
[2013-08-09 07:04:22] bind: Cannot assign requested address
[2013-08-09 07:04:22] network plugin: network_config_add_listen: sockent_open failed.
```

with the network plugins server configuration part as below;

```
<Plugin network>
#   # client setup:
#   Server "ff18::efc0:4a42" "25826"
#   <Server "239.192.74.66" "25826">
#       SecurityLevel Encrypt
#       Username "user"
#       Password "secret"
#       Interface "eth0"
#   </Server>
#   TimeToLive "128"
#
#   # server setup:
#   Listen "ff18::efc0:4a42" "25826"
    Listen  "172.16.7.200"
    Listen  "172.16.7.201"
#   <Listen "172.16.7.200" "2000">
#       SecurityLevel Sign
#       AuthFile "/etc/collectd/passwd"
#       Interface "eth2"
#   </Listen>
#   <Listen "172.16.7.201" "2000">
#       Interface "eth2"
#   </Listen>
#   MaxPacketSize 1024
#
#   # proxy setup (client and server as above):
#   Forward true
#
#   # statistics about the network plugin itself
#   ReportStats true
#
#   # "garbage collection"
#   CacheFlush 1800
</Plugin>
```

the data collection is working properly locally as I checked in the client the problem comes from the server only.

Do I have any misconfiguration?

Comment: Are you sure another instance of collectd isn't already running? Have you tried binding to a different port, other than the default port `25826`?

Comment: Yes, I tried in every possible port. I'm not sure that it's problematic because of ESXi or not? Because, I installed Collectd as VM in ESXi.

Comment: (I would rather add this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation). I recently stumbled across something similar which was actually a mis-configuration on my behalf very similar to what is described in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-cisco/+bug/1199012 "bug report").